# OpenCV and gstreamer rtsp server

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I am trying to setup a rtsp-server to re-stream an rtsp-stream of an IP camera after editing with OpenCV. Capturing the rtsp-stream and editing the frames work, but I cannot get the rtsp-server working. I receive the following error message:

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/opencv-4.1.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (896) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to query duration of stream
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/opencv-4.1.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (933) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=1, value=0, duration=-1
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/opencv-4.1.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1757) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module appsrc0 reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/opencv-4.1.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1663) writeFrame OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error pushing buffer to GStreamer pipeline
```

I tried two different pipes as you can see in the code below, but both receive the same error messages.

I try to access the rtsp-stream in VLC player by rtsp://192.168.y.y:8554/test, but the connection cannot be established.

Where is my mistake? Any suggestions for debugging? I have no experience with GStreamer.

I am using
Python: 3.7.3,
OpenCV: 4.1.1,
GStreamer: 1.14.4.0

```
import time
import cv2
import sys
print("Python: {}".format(sys.version))
print("OpenCV: {}".format(cv2.__version__))

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstApp', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib, GstApp, GstRtspServer, GObject

print("Gst: {}.{}.{}.{}".format(*Gst.version()))

_ = GstApp
__ = GstRtspServer

Gst.init()

camSet_h265 = 'rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.x.x:8554/12 latency=0 buffer-mode=auto ! queue ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink drop=1'
camSet = camSet_h265

pipe_out = 'appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1'
# pipe_out = ' appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1'


cam= cv2.VideoCapture(camSet, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
time.sleep(2)

ret, frame = cam.read()
frame_num = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
frame_width = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
frame_fps = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

fourcc_fmt = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(pipe_out, fourcc=fourcc_fmt, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, fps=frame_fps, frameSize=(frame_width, frame_height), isColor=True)
time.sleep(2)

while 1:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(20,100),(200,300),(0,255,0),8)
    # cv2.imshow('nanoCam',frame)
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Not sure for your case, but VideoWriter may expect float value for fps. Try: `..., fps=float(frame_fps), ...`

Comment: Thank you. This eliminiated the error 1757.
But the other three errors 896, 933 and 1663 are still there :(

Comment: The first 2 ones are just warnings saying the there is no duration (which is expected for a live stream) so current position cannot be computed.

Answer (score 0):

Main cause is that your writer pipeline has no sink. From opencv you may better use RTP streaming adding udpsink (that is appended by test-launch after pay0):

```
# Multicast to LAN (better avoid with wifi)
pipe_out = 'appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink port=5004 host=224.1.1.1'

# Single receiver
pipe_out = 'appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink port=5004 host=target_host_IP auto-multicast=0'
```

Also note that fourcc is useless with gstreamer backend, so just use 0.

Then you would create a SDP file for receiver such as:

```
m=video 5004 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 224.1.1.1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

**Be sure that no firewall rule prevents UDP/5004 from server to receiver.**
Then you may be able to receive with VLC opening the SDP file:

```
cvlc test.sdp
```

If you really want to use RTSP streaming (that will automatically send the SDP to client), it is possible to use shmsink/shmsrc such as [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/jetson-tx2-rtsp-streaming-ffmpeg-or-gstreamer/153907/5), but this is not an efficient solution, it may have some CPU overhead, so if trying this you would also check CPU usage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I did not succeed. I added the sink and now I do not get any gstreamer error message anymore. But I cannot access the sdp file. I opened port 5004 on my Windows 10 remote machine but no data is received by VLC: "live555 error: no data received in 10s, aborting". I changed the IP adress in the sdp file to the host IP.
The server is a raspberry pi running raspbian buster. I installed VLC on the host as well and tried to access the stream directly on the host to omit any firewall of the client, but I get the same error message in vlc. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited my answer now using multcast address in SDP (in single host mode it may work as well), adding insert-vui in x264enc. VLC may issue a warning about deadlock prevention. It may take 10s to run. If not, be sure you can send data on UDP/5004 from sender to receiver.

Comment: For ruling out opencv writer, you may use gstreamer from terminal such as: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=2000 insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! udpsink port=5004 host=224.1.1.1`

Comment: Finally I found some time to work on this problem again. I ran the following pipeline on the Raspberry Pi from the terminal:
`./test-launch --gst-debug=3 "( videotestsrc  ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"`
On the receiver I had access by opening the network stream with vlc:
 `rtsp://192.168.x.x:8554/test`
Obviously I previously had some firewall restriction explicitly for vlc which didn't allow vlc to access the port 8554.
Now I am trying to make the same pipeline working with opencv:

Comment: `camSet = 'videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! appsink'`
`pipe_out = 'appsrc  ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96'`
fourcc_fmt = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'h264')
The output I defined as
`out = cv2.VideoWriter(pipe_out, fourcc=fourcc_fmt, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, fps=30, frameSize=(640, 480), isColor=True)`
In the main loop I read a frame from the source pipe `camSet`and stream it out via
`out.write(frame)`

Comment: Reading the frame works an I can display it with `cv2.imshow`. But when writing the stream to the output pipe I receive the following error:
`[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/opencv-4.1.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1663) writeFrame OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error pushing buffer to GStreamer pipeline`
What could be the problem?

Comment: This error shows up with every frame.
vlc shows error messages that it cannot connect to the stream (even though I use the same rtsp-network-stream that worked without opencv).
I use:
[GCC 8.3.0]
OpenCV: 4.1.1
Gst: 1.14.4.0

Comment: Check after VideoWriter creation if it is opened (`out.isOpened()`). As said in my answer, for gstreamer backend you don't have to provide a 4CC. I just use 0. Also note that fps should be a float value such as fps=float(30). If not working with these be sure you don't have a processing in the loop taking too much time and framerate couldn't be acheived because of that.

Comment: Thx for your reply! VideoWriter ist open. fourcc = 0. fps = float(30). In the main loop I had a cv2.imshow() command that obviously used too much CPU. I removed it. Now the error message (1663) is gone. I do not receive any errors anymore but I still cannot connect to the stream. Should gstreamer respond with "stream ready at rtsp://192.168.x.x" like in the test-launch example? How do I know the broadcasting channel? I expect it to be rtsp://192.168.x.x:8554/test but maybe it has to be something different since I am running it now from opencv?

Comment: I tried your proposal with udpsink as well `pipe_out = 'appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink port=5004 host=target_host_IP auto-multicast=0'`. I do not receive any errors on the server, but in VLC the stream does not show up at the receiver. VLC does not give any errors either. The firewall at the receiver is switched off. Note that this stream does not open in VLC on the server, either.

Comment: You may try setting `key-int-max=30` into `x264enc` properties. Also note that BGR->BGRx->YUV is useless, videoconvert may convert BGR into some YUV format expected by x264enc.